# Boost::Container::Vector with Enum Template Argument - Not Legal Base Class

Tags: c++, stl, boost, vector, enums

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with the Boost v1.42.0 library.  If I use an enum as the template argument, I get a compile error when adding a value using `push_back()`.  The compiler error is: `'T': is not a legal base class` and the location of the error is `move.hpp` line 79.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>

class Test {
public:
 enum Types {
  Unknown = 0,
  First = 1,
  Second = 2,
  Third = 3
 };
 typedef boost::container::vector<Types> TypesVector;
};

int main() {
 Test::TypesVector o;

 o.push_back(Test::First);

 return 0;
}
```

If I use a `std::vector` instead it works.  And if I resize the Boost version first and then set the values using the `[]` operator it also works.

Is there some way to make this work using `push_back()`?

---

Template backtrace of the error:

```
error C2516: 'T' : is not a legal base class
1>        main.cpp(21) : see declaration of 'T'
1>        main.cpp(21) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::interprocess::rv' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Test::Types
1>        ]
```

Comment: It appears that your error is inside their C++03 implementation of C++0x rvalue references. Can you provide the template instantiation backtrace?

Comment: Did you still want the backtrace?  Or did you take it into account with your answer below?  And how would I do that?  Is there a automated process or would it just be manual copying?

Comment: The backtrace is the series of error messages "While instatiating … during instantiation of … in template … etc"

Comment: I added the text from the output window of the error...

Comment: that's not a backtrace, it's just one error. Is that the entire output of your compiler? Did you try my more limited fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have find really a bug. I have posted to the Boost ML to track the issue and try to have more info.

For the moment the single workaround I see is to specialize the rv class as follows, but I'm not sure this will work on all the cases.

```
namespace boost {
namespace interprocess {

template <>
class rv<Test::Types> 
{
   Test::Types v;
   rv();
   ~rv();
   rv(rv const&);
   void operator=(rv const&);
   operator Test::Types() const {return v;}
};

}}
```

If this do not works you can try using int instead of enum.

```
 enum {
  Unknown = 0,
  First = 1,
  Second = 2,
  Third = 3
 };
 typedef int Types;
```

Of course this has the drawback to loss the enum safety.

Comment: That appears to be a successful work around.  It compiles and lets me go on my way.  Could you post any links to the bug items you submit to Boost?  Thank you.

Comment: I have not yet posted a ticket, but I have started a thread on this issue (<http://old.nabble.com/-interprocess--move--enum-template-argument-fails-to-be-a-valid-base-class-tt28322112.html> and <http://old.nabble.com/Fwd%3A-Re%3A--interprocess--move--enum-template-argument-fails-to-be-a-valid-base-class-tt28325178.html>. Ion, the author of Boost.Interprocess is not confident with my workaround and is looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Boost has some erroneous logic to determine whether to derive from `T` or not.

Naively, one might assume that any type besides a native type or pointer may be used as a base. However `enum`s are neither bases nor primitive. Perhaps they failed to account for that.

It looks like Boost is incorrectly determining that `enum`s are compatible with its rvalue-reference emulation.

The best way to solve this is to avoid use of enums in Boost Interprocess structures.

A hack like

```
namespace boost {
namespace interprocess { // get inside boost
template<>
class is_movable<Test::Types> // add custom specialization of is_movable
   : public ::boost::mpl::bool_<false>
{};
}}
```

might patch things up. Untested.

Add this right after your `#include`s so it appears before the first use.

Comment: Boost v1.42.0 is the latest version.

Comment: @CuppM: Sorry, upon review of the partial specialization rules, §14.5.4/9 bullet 3 says "— The argument list of the specialization shall not be identical to the implicit argument list of the primary
template." So my code was broken. I suggest changing to a `vector<int>` or `vector<char>` because Boost doesn't support this. For the sake of argument, hmm, I'll post a patch for just your one type.

Comment: Now I get:  

`'boost::interprocess::is_movable<Test::Types>' : symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'move_detail'`

Comment: @CuppM: I misread the header. Remove the `move_detail` namespace enclosure.

Comment: Nope.  That block compiles without error, but it still results in a `'T': is not a legal base class` error.

Comment: @CuppM it comes back to knowing where the error is coming from, and you still haven't posted a backtrace. For example, this fix only works for one enum type. You'll get the same error if you're using two. Why don't you want to copy-paste your error messages?

Comment: I did copy and paste the error message from the output window in Visual Studio.  That's what I added to the end of my question above.  If I should be looking somewhere else, let me know and I'll post it.